# Variable does not exist: MEDIA_TYPE__c

Tags: httprequest

I have created custom fileds in Big Object to save my logs there. And trying to assign one of custom objects

```
public class my_Log {
    public static void log(EventType eType, String requestId, RestRequest request, RestResponse response, String userId) {
            MEDIA_TYPE__c = RestContext.request.headers?.get('Content-Type');
```

---

> Variable does not exist: MEDIA_TYPE__c

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more code and describe exactly what you are trying to do.  If `Media_Type__c` is a custom field, you need to instantiate the object first before you can assign a value to the field.

Comment: done. is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code you're assigning a value to a variable (`MEDIA_TYPE__C`) without first declaring the variable. You can declare and assign the value at the same time if you include the type for `MEDIA_TYPE__C` which, without knowing what you intend to do, I would start with a `String` type.

EDIT: As @JefersonChaves pointed out, you will also need to change your variable name as variables cannot end in "__c" in Apex because it conflicts with custom field names.

```java
public class my_Log {
    public static void log(EventType eType, String requestId, RestRequest request, RestResponse response, String userId) {
        String mediaType = RestContext.request.headers?.get('Content-Type');

        //... the rest of your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now it says: Invalid character in identifier: MEDIA_TYPE__c

Comment: That is because variables should not end with __c, only custom field api names. So I guess you have a custom field and is trying to insert this value, what is the big object name?